# VBA Print .SelectedItem with MsgBox

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

I am trying to print the selected filename for debugging purposes using a simple MsgBox. msoFileDialogOpen allows the user to select the file. I am trying to print the file name of the selected file.

```
'   Start File Explorer to select file containing data
Dim lngCount As Long
' Open the file dialog
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    .AllowMultiSelect = True
    .Show

'   Display paths of each file selected
    For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
        MsgBox .SelectedItems
    Next lngCount
End With
```

When I run this I get the error message "Run-time error '450': Wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment".

Answer (score 3):

Looks like your message box is trying to show the whole collection (`.SelectedItems`) rather than one at a time (`.SelectedItems(lngCount)`). Does it work if you put this?

```
For lngCount = 1 To .SelectedItems.Count
    MsgBox .SelectedItems(lngCount)
Next lngCount
```

Or simpler, this might work, too:

```
For Each filename In .SelectedItems
    MsgBox filename
Next
```

Answer (score 1):

`.SelectedItems` cannot be displayed directly (as it cannot be coerced to a text string) so `MsgBox .SelectedItems` is not valid.

To display a specific selected item, use  `MsgBox .SelectedItems(lngCount)`

Answer (score 1):

You were trying to display a `Collection` (selecteditem**S**) and the `MsgBox` only accept a `String`.

Just switch to the line below :

```
MsgBox .SelectedItems(lngCount)
```